# /dev/null No such file or directory

Tags: osx-elcapitan, dev-null

I run `El Capitan OS X` and am trying to use `/dev/null` however when I do anything with it, for example `ls`:

```
ls -l /dev/null
ls: /dev/null: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

However that outputs the following:

```
mknod: illegal option -- m
usage: mknod [-F format] name [b | c] major minor
       mknod [-F format] name [b | c] major unit subunit
       mknod name [b | c] number
       mknod name w
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/239029/what-would-prevent-me-from-re-creating-a-missing-dev-null-folder) mark as dupe

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the answer provided from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/239029/what-would-prevent-me-from-re-creating-a-missing-dev-null-folder) along with the question itself. The fix for this issue is as follows:

```
sudo -s << _EOF 
mknod /dev/null c 3 2
chmod 666 /dev/null
_EOF
```